# Struts 2 jQuery Grid reload issue

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I have following jqGrid in my page

```jsp
<sjg:grid           id="reportGrid" 
             gridModel="gridModel" 
             autowidth="true" 
          reloadTopics="refreshGrid" gridview="true"  
  onGridCompleteTopics="gridLoadComplete"           
       onSuccessTopics="dataLoadCompleted"   
             navigator="true" 
                 pager="true" 
       navigatorSearch="true" 
navigatorSearchOptions="{multipleSearch:true}" 
                scroll="true" 
                rowNum="10000" 
             hoverrows="false" 
       groupColumnShow="false" 
            groupField="['field1','field2']" 
                  href="webReport" 
               formIds="myform" 
              dataType="json" 
              loadonce="true" >
    ..........................
    ..........................
    ..........................
</sjg:grid>
```

and a button

```jsp
<sj:a button="true" 
  buttonIcon="ui-icon-refresh" 
  buttonText="true"  
     onclick="reloadGridFunc();">
    Submit
</sj:a>
```

and in JS I have this

```js
function reloadGridFunc()
{
    
    $("#reportGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'});      
    $.publish("refreshGrid");
    
    // $("#reportGrid")
    //  .jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"userReport",datatype:"json"}).
    trigger("reloadGrid");
        
}

$.subscribe('gridLoadComplete', function(event, data) {
    // $("#reportGrid").jqGrid('clearGridData');    
    // $('#reportGrid').setGridParam({ page: 1, datatype: "json"})
    //    .trigger('reloadGrid');   
    // $("#reportGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');          
});
  
$.subscribe('dataLoadCompleted', function(event, data) { 
    // $("#reportGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

but what I am seeing is that the grid populates with new data but the grouping is not cleared; I have to press the reload button on bottom of the grid to refresh the grid, and after that the data representation looks fine.

I have a form in which a grid , anchor and other HTML elements exists, and according top these I select different criteria and click the button, the grid is populated and when I change the criteria the grid repopulating, but the old grouping is preserved. I have to press the reload button in grid to fix this.

Comment: Why are your function bodies all commented ?

Comment: because i tried these but was not working

Comment: @AndreaLigios have any idea what might be wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the grid is completed it checks for the subscribers of the `onGridCompleteTopics`.

> A comma delimited list of topics that published after all the data is
>   loaded into the grid and all other processes are complete.

---

When the grid is succeeded it checks for the subscribers of the `onSuccessTopics`.

> A comma delimited list of topics that published when the element ajax request is completed successfully (will override settings for a target container if provided).

---

If no subscribers is found for the topic event, they won't be bound to the grid. So, make sure you subscribe to the grid before it checks for topic's subscribers.

See an [example](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) of grid with topics.

The code to reload grid

```
</sjg:grid>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reportGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
  });
</script>
```

---

Comment: onGridCompleteTopics is called but onSuccessTopics is not called and i debugged it and noted that due to the async call the $("#reportGrid").trigger('reloadGrid') was not working if i create an other button and on that call reloadgrig trigger then grid reload fines

Comment: You doing something else rather than `$("#reportGrid").trigger('reloadGrid')`.

Comment: actually after this $.publish("refreshGrid"); the gid data is reloaded but the groups are not i.e the group old text stays and when i press the reload button it is then refreshed , so thats why i am calling reload trigger

Comment: So, why not you are calling this in the topic handler?

Comment: Did you change `href` attribute of the grid tag?

Comment: can u send me the pm to agha.ali22@gmail.com so i can send u the code

Comment: let me give you an example , first time grid loads ok(with two groups let say grp1 and grp2) but but i press the button the result comes back fine, but let say that this result only contain grp1 result but i am seeing grp empty got my point what is the issue.